# loop through meta_query relations

Tags: php

I am currently working on a project which uses WP_Query to XML conversion so that you can filter through the XML like you would in a normal query. The data only exists in the XML so there is no database tables and/or data as its form an external party.

The query is like this as you would normally in WP_Query and this works in the XML parser, this would generate an url like
https://example.com/cars/?brand=Renault,Mercedes

Query

```
                $filters = array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'brand',
                        'value' => 'Renault',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'brand',
                        'value' => 'Mercedes',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
                );
```

XML Function which reads through relation and reruns the function this if statement lives in.

```
        if ( array_key_exists( 'relation', $query ) ) {
            $new_query = $query;
            $relation  = $query['relation'];
            unset( $new_query['relation'] );

            return $this->compare_meta_query( $new_query, $item, $relation );
        }
```

However if the filtering gets more complex like:
https://example.com/cars/?brand=Renault,Mercedes&fuel=Electric

The query would look like this

```
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'brand',
                        'value' => 'Renault',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'brand',
                        'value' => 'Mercedes',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'fuel',
                            'value' => 'Electric',
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        ),
                    )
                );
```

But the function above no longer returns the desired results as it doesn't look through a multi-dimensional array and doesn't see the second relation.

How would i go on to solve this or expand this function to support it like WordPres does?
I know it needs to know if it's multi-dimensional but I lost sight on how to proceed.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with WordPress. If you're writing code to filter XML, then that's a pure PHP issue. You'd be better off asking at stackoverflow.com. Although you will want to include more code, such as the code for the `compare_meta_query()` method.